# Using serve-handler to update custom headers

Tags: html, response-headers, serve

I'm trying to use serve-handler to make a custom response header to change the content-disposition.
Unfortunately I am a complete beginner so I am way out of my comfort zone and struggling to proceed past using npm install to install the serve-handler package.
Specifically, how do I now add it to the https server? And where to create the file that specifies new custom headers. Any help greatly appreciated, thank you

I have tried using this code

```
const handler = require('serve-handler');
 
module.exports = async (request, response) => {
  await handler(request, response);
};
```

that I found when downloading serve-handler but there is a lack of more precise instructions, and when I run it I get a "no matches found" error